# Join Mysql not working well

Tags: mysql, join

I have this query :

```
$criteria = new CDbCriteria ;
$criteria->select = "usuarioproyectotiendaid, upt.usuarioid,
                         proyecto.*, upt.tiendaid, upt.fechainicio, estado.estadodsc,
                         upt.lunes, upt.martes, upt.miercoles, upt.jueves, upt.viernes,upt.sabado, upt.domingo,
                         t.tiendaid, t.clienteid, canal.canaldsc, formatodsc, ciudaddsc, regiondsc, ndeterminante,
                         td.telefono, td.contacto, td.horaIni, td.horaFin, td.latitude, td.longitude,
                         sucursal, nielsen, tienda, calle, colonia, cp, t.activo" ;
    $criteria->join =" join usuarioproyectotienda upt on upt.tiendaid = t.tiendaid and upt.usuarioid=".$usuarioid;
    $criteria->join.=" join canal on canal.canalid = t.canalid";
    $criteria->join.=" join formato on formato.formatoid = t.formatoid";
    $criteria->join.=" join ciudad on ciudad.ciudadid = t.ciudadid";
    $criteria->join.=" join region on region.regionid = t.regionid";
    $criteria->join.=" join tienda_detalles td on td.tienda_id = t.tiendaid";
    $criteria->join.=" join proyecto on proyecto.proyectoid = upt.proyectoid";
    $criteria->join.=" join estado on estado.estadoid = t.ciudadid";
```

When the table tienda_detalles is full, everything is ok (5 results), but when I delete datas in this table, query does not give me any results.

This table is just optional data that complete the info in the table "tienda", so if there is no data, I should still have 5 result, how can I do it???

If needed, I can publish real sql query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use `LEFT JOIN` instead of `JOIN`.

`JOIN` requires data in the joining tables but `LEFT JOIN` allows them to be null if no rows have been found.

Comment: It seems to have the same results.

Comment: @JuliatzindelToro, `LEFT OUTER JOIN` and `LEFT JOIN` both are synonym.